# solving 2d heat equation using mpi

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, differential-equations

Basically, I am trying to solve the **2d** heat equation using **OpenMPI**.
We start off with a matrix(which represents the heat distribution of a 2-dimensional object) with the heat at the bottom(i.e, all the bottom values are **100**), time passes and all the heat flows from the hotter surface to the colder surface and we are simulating this through each iteration.

We start off

```
int max_iterations = 15000;
double epsilon = 1.0e-3;

int N = 20;
int M = 20;

// Initialize MPI
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int pid, np;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

// Calculate the number of rows per process
int rows_per_process = M / np;
rows_per_process += 2; // boundary rows
```

then we declare and initialize the local matrix by dividing the main matrix horizontally in to np parts where np is number of processes

```
Matrix U(rows_per_process, N);
Matrix W(rows_per_process, N);

// Init & Boundary
for (i = 0; i < rows_per_process; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        U(i, j) = 0.0;
    }
}

for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    U(rows_per_process - 1, j) = 100.0;
}
```

after that, we distribute the boundaries of local matrices to the other processes (this is the part, I think doesn't work as expected)

```
// Check if this is not process 0
if (pid != 0) {
    MPI_Send(&U(1, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&U(0, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}

// Check if this is not the last process
if (pid != np - 1) {
    MPI_Send(&U(rows_per_process-2, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&U(rows_per_process-1, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

after this main loop begins

```
iteration_count = 0;
do
{
    iteration_count++;
    diffnorm = 0.0;

    for (i = 1; i < rows_per_process - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < N - 1; ++j)
        {
            W(i, j) = (U(i, j + 1) + U(i, j - 1) + U(i + 1, j) + U(i - 1, j)) * 0.25;
            diffnorm += (W(i, j) - U(i, j)) * (W(i, j) - U(i, j));
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i < rows_per_process - 1; ++i)
        for (j = 1; j < N - 1; ++j)
            U(i, j) = W(i, j);


    // Check if this is not process 0
    if (pid != 0) {
        MPI_Send(&U(1, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&U(0, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }

    // Check if this is not the last process
    if (pid != np - 1) {
        MPI_Send(&U(rows_per_process-2, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&U(rows_per_process-1, 0), N, MPI_DOUBLE, pid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,                  MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }

    diffnorm = sqrt(diffnorm);
    MPI_Allreduce(&diffnorm, &diffnorm, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} while (epsilon <= diffnorm && iteration_count < max_iterations);
```

after this we gather the processed data from the children (this part is also in doubt)

```
Matrix U_MPI(M, N);
int nElm = N*(rows_per_process -2), nth = (pid*(rows_per_process - 2));

MPI_Gather(&U(1, 0), nElm, MPI_DOUBLE,
           &U_MPI(nth, 0), nElm, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

**OUTPUT**

0 0.93421 1.67984 2.09131 2.09131 1.67984 0.93421 0

0 2.05719 3.69419 4.59451 4.59451 3.69419 2.05719 0

0 3.60071 6.44586 7.99882 7.99882 6.44586 3.60071 0

0 5.90026 10.4906 12.9572 12.9572 10.4906 5.90026 0

0 9.51028 16.6601 20.3833 20.3833 16.6601 9.51028 0

0 15.4813 26.2571 31.5339 31.5339 26.2571 15.4813 0

0 26.1585 41.3538 47.9623 47.9623 41.3538 26.1585 0

**Expected output**

0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000

0.000000    2.285033    4.078976    5.051108    5.051108    4.078976    2.285033    0.000000

0.000000    5.061334    8.980086   11.074751   11.074751    8.980086    5.061334    0.000000

0.000000    8.980539   15.705866   19.193785   19.193785   15.705866    8.980539    0.000000

0.000000   15.155358   25.669779   30.801644   30.801644   25.669779   15.155358    0.000000

0.000000   25.971518   41.016975   47.542273   47.542273   41.016975   25.971518    0.000000

0.000000   47.714062   64.884910   70.808927   70.808927   64.884910   47.714062    0.000000

100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000

**Matrix**

```
struct Mat {
    int height;
    int width;
    std::vector<double> data;
    
    Mat();
    
    Mat(int height, int width) 
        : height(height), width(width), data(height*width)
    {    }

    double& operator()(int h, int w) {
        int id = h*width + w;
        if(id >= (height * width)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid acess");
        }
        return data[h*width + w];
    }
};
```

Comment: do you have a quesiton?

Comment: kudos for using a `vector<double>` for the matrix!

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```cpp
for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    U(rows_per_process - 1, j) = 100.0;
}
```

Appears to be initializing the boundary condition into the lowest ghost-zone row on *each process*, not the lowest row of the domain. Is that what you intended?

Also here:

```cpp
int nElm = N*(rows_per_process -2), nth = (pid*(rows_per_process - 2));

MPI_Gather(&U(1, 0), nElm, MPI_DOUBLE,
           &U_MPI(nth, 0), nElm, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The `&U_MPI(nth, 0)` expression looks like an out-of-bounds access.

There may be other problems...